# "Pessimistic offline lock" with third party concurrent writers

Tags: c#, database, design-patterns, concurrency

We have an application that reads and writes to a third party data storage.
The code of that data storage is closed source, we do not know about it and can not change it.
There is only a slim API that allows reading and writing to it.

An [pessimistic offline lock](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pessimisticOfflineLock.html) helps to span transactions and have concurrent applications work with it. That will work fine I believe.

But now we have the problem that other software will also write and read to that storage
and our application shall update when changes in that data storage happen. The data storage itself does not provide any notification. The third party software will not change some global state that indicates that something has changed.

Is there any kind of pattern or best practise to "observe" that data storage and
publish events to update all clients (of our software)?

I really do not want to periodically read, compare and publish events if it is not
absolutely the last resort. Perhaps someone has a better idea here?

Comment: What is the third party data storage?

Comment: A non-System implemented Pessimistic Offline Lock requires cooperation/participation/enforcement among all possible modifers of the data.  This is generally not possible and is one of the two reasons that this approach is rarely taken in modern software.

To do anything remotely like this (i.e., with multiple heterogenuous writers) in a useful way requires some kind help/assistance from the System facilities themselves.

Comment: @rie819 It is a not widely known database like storage, does not matter here, as it is an architectural question.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Okay, what would be a modern alternative to that? Can you propose some solution for that kind of problem please? What is the second reason?

Comment: @MareInfinitus The second reason is the problems of determining and resolving abandoned locks. As for possible solutions, if you persist in viewing this as just an OOD issue, then either optimistic offline locks, which still need some System help, but much less, or avoid the issue altogether through more detailed state-progression/control in your data model. *MY* approach, however, would be to recognize that this if primarily an issue of the data-stores capabilities and start there, looking to use System-provided lock/transaction control, which both 1) works and 2) is how it is usually done.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Okay, then I make a service which is a proxy for the datastore, which handles transactions, concurrency and updates. The datastore will not provide these. Can you elaborate on the "system-provided lock/transaction control" part please?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Please also note that I do not persist in seeing this as a OOD issue, but OOD is just the first way for me to solve this issue. If there are better ways please let me know. Would be glad to hear about it and would love to accept your answer.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Sorry, wrong tone on my part.  AFAIK, issues of synchronizing multi-writer access always have to start with "*What tools/controls/facilities are available to constrain, divert and/or track the out-of-application writers?*"  What you can accomplish is practically limited by those facilities.  For instance, if you can force all access through a service of your own, then you can do almost anything.  But if all you have is the OS's file-locking and file-modification-dates, then you are a lot more constrained.  And if you don't have even that, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: @RBarryYoung In fact I do not have direct access to the data store, it is hosted on some server and I have no control over the other applications that read and write to it. Right now, the best I can think of is having a service as a proxy which periodically queries the store, compares it to an older state and fires update events to my clients if some other application has altered it (and fire some other event if my application alters it to notify my own clients, leaving the other applications with their own problems). It sound not very good to me, but it probably does the job.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Yep, that's about all you can do, and that only supports Optimistic Concurrency (partially), not Pessimistic.  You might get improvements by adding some kind of checksum/hash to your stored data, but that's only an optimization.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Thank you for the discussion. If you provide some answer, I will be pleased to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-System implemented Pessimistic Offline Lock requires cooperation/participation/enforcement among all possible modifers of the data. This is generally not possible and is one of the two reasons that this approach is rarely taken in modern software. To do anything remotely like this (i.e., with multiple heterogenuous writers) in a useful way requires some kind help/assistance from the System facilities themselves. (The second reason is the issues of determining and resolving abandoned locks, very problematic).

As for possible solutions, then from a purely design viewpoint, either optimistic offline locks, which still need some System help, but much less, or avoid the issue altogether through more detailed state-progression/control in your data model.

My approach, however, would be to set-aside the design question (initially) recognizing that this is primarily an issue of the data-store's capabilities and start there, looking to use System-provided lock/transaction control, (which both 1: usually works and 2: is how it is usually done).

AFAIK, issues of synchronizing multi-writer access always have to start with "*What tools/controls/facilities are available to constrain, divert and/or track the out-of-application writers?*" What you can accomplish is practically limited by those facilities.

For instance, if you can force all access through a service of your own, then you can do almost anything. But if all you have is the OS's file-locking and file-modification-dates, then you are a lot more constrained. And if you don't have even that, then there's not much you can do.

> In fact I do not have direct access to the data store, it is hosted on
>   some server and I have no control over the other applications that
>   read and write to it. Right now, the best I can think of is having a
>   service as a proxy which periodically queries the store, compares it
>   to an older state and fires update events to my clients if some other
>   application has altered it (and fire some other event if my
>   application alters it to notify my own clients, leaving the other
>   applications with their own problems). It sound not very good to me,
>   but it probably does the job.

Yep, that's about all you can do, and that only supports Optimistic Concurrency (partially), not Pessimistic. You might get improvements by adding some kind of checksum/hash to your stored data, but that's only an optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much for the discussion!